# Get URL Exact displayed text

Tags: php, httprequest, ascii

I'm trying to use an ASCII-Art Generator API with images so I use this PHP function:

($string is the URL)

```
echo(strip_tags($string));
```

But this returns the text without the spaces, so this isn't the exact text.

So, I'm looking for a function to have the EXACT text, can someone help me?

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion to use `strip_tags`. (Take in mind that you've kept your source a secret and we can only guess what you're talking about.)

Comment: Uh, i don't know if i can put links so, sorry..

Comment: strip_tags is the only one function i found to get the displayed text without the html code

Comment: Chances are that the "ASCII" output depends on the explicit HTML styling (such as `<pre>`-formatted text); so yes, removing it is not what you want before understanding how it works.

Comment: Give us the value of `$string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you're using something like: `http://artii.herokuapp.com/`

The response will be in `text/plain`.

> But this returns the text without the spaces, so this isn't the exact
>   text.

Dissecting that I believe you mean `newlines` not spaces.

You would need to wrap the response in a `<pre>` tag.

```
<?php
$ascii = file_get_contents('http://artii.herokuapp.com/make?text=ASCII+art');

echo '<pre>'.$ascii.'</pre>';
```

Or use CSS to style the div like a `pre`

```
<style>
    .ascii {
        display: block;
        unicode-bidi: embed;
        font-family: monospace;
        white-space: pre;
    }
</style>

<?php
$ascii = file_get_contents('http://artii.herokuapp.com/make?text=ASCII+art');

echo '<div class="ascii">'.$ascii.'</div>';
```

Comment: np, glad to help